# Query over large tables get timout in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am running simple queries like (`Select top 10 records, joins, counts, group by`) to fetch rows and stats according to requirement. Tables have around 150,000 to 200,000 rows. All primary keys and foreign keys are well defined.

But I'm receiving timeout error randomly while running queries. Same query or stored procedure takes different time to complete. Database is hosted on a shared server. I set the command timeout property to 600 but it's not working. My service provider said that there system will kill the query after 30 seconds if the processing is not done. They told me to tune up the query to match up the time.

Eg.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[NP_TableReport]  
(    
 @CreatedOnFrom datetime = NULL,  
 @CreatedOnTo datetime = NULL
)    
AS    
BEGIN  

 SELECT COUNT(ID) [Count]    
 FROM Table1
 WHERE     
     (@CreatedOnFrom IS NULL OR @CreatedOnFrom <= CreatedOn)  
 AND (@CreatedOnTo IS NULL OR @CreatedOnTo >= CreatedOn)  
END
```

Please tell me what is causing the random timeout error? When I tried the same thing on a dedicated server the error is gone. Can anybody please explain what is going on?

Comment: Solar flares? Riots? Oscillation?

Comment: Do you have other processes that could be querying the same tables at the same time you are doing your tests?

Comment: Foreign keys seem of little consequence in this query. Do you actually have *indexes* on CreatedOn?

Comment: If you execute your queries with the same parameters, have you sometimes this timeout or is it parameters dependant ?

Comment: `WHERE     
 AND` = syntax error?

Comment: @mbeckish Multiple user are executing the same procedure several times simultaneously. And many of them are facing the error.

Comment: Try adding WITH(NOLOCK) to your query to see if it is just a contention issue.

Comment: Also, please provide the real SQL (your questions mentions TOP and GROUP BY which are not present in your sample SQL).

Comment: WITH(NO LOCK) error is gone. But this is not the right way. This will lead to a uncommited read and which is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more than 200K tuples, an average query could easily take more than 30 seconds to complete. If your hosting provider don't allows a query to take more than 30 secs, consider fetching and filtering the data using client-side technologies. If even that fails to work, then consider changing your hosting provider or buying a separate database hosting for your application.

You have mentioned that you've already created an Index on "createdOn" column. I think your query and database state is currently in its most optimized form. Only removing the timeout constraint imposed by your hosting provider can solve your problem.

Comment: Any suggestions for hosting provider?

Answer (score 5):

Start by adding an index on `Table1` with the `CreateOn` field.

Use `count(*)` rather than `count(id)`, unless you specifically want to count non-null values in the `id` column.

Depending on your input values, you have four different queries, so it may help to specialize them:

```
if (@CreatedOnFrom is null and @CreatedOnTo is null) begin

  select count(*) [count]
  from Table1

end else if (@CreatedOnFrom is null) begin

  select count(*) [count]
  from Table1
  where @CreatedOnTo >= CreatedOn

end else if (@CreatedOnTo is null) begin

  select count(*) [count]
  from Table1
  where @CreatedOnFrom <= CreatedOn

end else begin

  select count(*) [count]
  from Table1
  where @CreatedOnTo >= CreatedOn and @CreatedOnFrom <= CreatedOn

end
```

Comment: Index is already added with the CreatedOn Field.

Comment: Can you post a query execution plan for the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would not put so much calculation in the query if it can be done beforehand.  Inequalities with nulls are often pretty gross, IMX.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[NP_TableReport]  
(    
 @CreatedOnFrom datetime = NULL,  
 @CreatedOnTo datetime = NULL
)    
AS    
BEGIN  

 SET @CreatedOnFrom = COALESCE(@CreatedOnFrom, CAST('01/01/1753' as datetime))
 SET @CreatedOnTo = COALESCE(@CreatedOnTo, CAST('12/31/9999' as datetime))

 SELECT COUNT(ID) [Count]    
 FROM dbo.Table1
 WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN @CreatedOnTo AND @CreatedOnFrom

END
```

Note that if `Table1.CreatedOn` contains a time component after midnight but you only want to submit dates to the procedure, you may need to use this instead:

```
 SET @CreatedOnTo = COALESCE(DATEADD(day,1,@CreatedOnTo), CAST('12/31/9999 23:59:59' as datetime))
```

You could even subtract a second from that to get the `DATEADD` to get the last possible second of the specified date.

You could put the `COALESCE` statements into the `WHERE` clause, but I find this easier to read.